# Golang visitor pattern for marshaling shapes as JSON, and XML

Tags: json, xml, go, serialization, visitor-pattern

I was trying to implement visitor pattern in Golang, and came across an idea of using a generic `func` type instead if `interface` as visitor. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Visitor func(shape Shape)

type Shape interface {
    accept(Visitor)
}

type Circle struct {
    Rad int
}

func (c Circle) accept(v Visitor) {
    v(c)
}

type Line struct {
    Length int
}

func (l Line) accept(v Visitor) {
    v(l)
}

func JsonVisitor(shape Shape) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(shape)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}

func XmlVisitor(shape Shape) {
    bytes, err := xml.Marshal(shape)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}

func main() {
    circle := Circle{12}
    line := Line{42}
    circle.accept(JsonVisitor)
    line.accept(JsonVisitor)

    circle.accept(XmlVisitor)
    line.accept(XmlVisitor)
}
```

Besides the code review I have a question: is it still considered a Visitor pattern if using one generic function for all the Shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General things:

- The visitor pattern is more suited for object-oriented languages. [Whether Go is object-oriented](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language) is up for debate, but fact is that many OOP patterns are implemented differently in it (or don't make sense at all).
- Specifically, I don't see an advantage to `XmlVisitor` and `JsonVisitor` over `xml.Marshal` and `json.Marshal`. That said, design is beyond the scope of codereview SE, so I'll assume you have a good reason.
- Create a separate package rather than adding to `main`. I understand this is something you'd do eventually, but it's good practise to do it from the very start.

---

```
type Visitor func(shape Shape)
```

Do you actually need this to be a type? I see little advantage to it (slightly shorter lines perhaps) and this effectively hides from the user what `Visitor` really is. `func (c Circle) accept(v func(Shape))` is self-documenting and easier to read. If you must have your own type, name it `VisitorFunc` at least, to make it clear what it is.

---

```
type Shape interface {
    accept(Visitor)
}
```

Probably not the best name - it can be anything, doesn't neccessarily need to be shape. I'd go with e.g. "Visitable", but the proper name per [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface-names) would be "Accepter" since it contains a single method (use your best judgement to decide which name is better).

More importantly, `accept` shouldn't be private - you won't be able to call private methods outside of the package where the type is defined.

---

```
func (c Circle) accept(v Visitor) {
    v(c)
}
```

You probably want to pass by reference (pointer): `func (c *Circle) accept...`. The way it is now, your visitor is read-only and also more costly, as the whole object is copied.

---

```
func JsonVisitor(shape Shape) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(shape)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}

func XmlVisitor(shape Shape) {
    bytes, err := xml.Marshal(shape)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

Don't `panic(...)`. [`panic` is used for *unrecoverable* errors](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#panic) - you'll only use it if you can answer "yes" to "am I confident that, whenever this errors happens, it's so severe that the best thing to do is just crash". Instead, have your `accept` method, your `Visitor` type and these functions all return `error`.

Comment: Design is certainly within the scope of Code Review, if you wish to discuss it further.

Comment: There are no advantages of this implementation over the go stdlib marshallers. This is just a example of an implementation of visitor pattern in go. So the goal is to show what these pattern is useful for. Thank you for a lot of useful remarks!